# $\psi$ continuous and g(Bounded variation) $\Rightarrow$ $\psi \circ g$ bounded variation?

Tags: measure-theory, bounded-variation

Suppose I have a function $\psi$ that is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$  and $g$ is a function with a bounded variation on $[0,1]$. Is it true that $\psi \circ g$   has a bounded variation on [0,1]?

If so, why?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean composition or convolution?

Comment: edited! thanks for pointing it out

Comment: There are continuous functions that are not of bounded variation.

Comment: such as ? can you give me more details

Comment: Such as $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\quad 0 &, x = 0 \\ x\sin \frac{\pi}{x} &, x \neq 0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is false. The function $\psi(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ with $\psi(0)=0$ is continuous. The identity function $g(x)=x$ has bounded variation on $[0,1]$, but $\psi \circ g=\psi$ does not have bounded variation on $[0,1]$.

To show $\psi$ does not have bounded variation, let $\{x_j\}=\{1/(\pi(k+1/2))\}$ then 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty |x_j \sin(1/x_j)|=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(k+1/2)}=\infty.$$

Comment: Ok, I understand the first part.  Now, i need to show that there exist a partition P such that $ \sum_{j=1}^k | \psi(t_j)- \psi(t_{j-1})| >M $ for a constant M. But im not sure how

Comment: It's kind of funny how it's always the same function that pops up as a counterexample.

Comment: @usere5225321 Let $t_j = \frac{1}{\pi(j+1/2)}$.

Comment: so i calculated the first 2 terms and this is what I get : $|\frac{1}{2 \pi}+\frac{2}{3 \pi}| + |\frac{-2}{3 \pi}- \frac{2.}{5 \pi} | $  etc etc. So how do I pick M? do i just take M=$\frac{1}{2 \pi}+\frac{2}{3 \pi}|$?

Comment: The series diverges: you don't pick $M$, but instead you show it's greater than $M$ for any $M$. (It's a harmonic series.)

Comment: @DanielFischer but since $\sin(\pi(j+1/2))= - \sin(\pi(j-1/2))$ and $|\sin(\pi(j+1/2))|=1$ for every positive integer j, we get the sum over $|1/(j+1/2)- 1/(j-1/2)| $ which converges

Comment: @usere5225321 No, since the signs are opposite, you have $\lvert \psi(t_{j+1}) - \psi(t_j)\rvert = \lvert \psi(t_{j+1})\rvert + \lvert \psi(t_j)\rvert$. The sum over that is divergent.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again for your help